# ALSA Audio Stuttering (RTL_FM, Raspberry Pi3)

Tags: c, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, pcm

I've been working on a project for a Raspberry Pi, using RTLSDR, specifically rtl_fm. source code is [here](https://github.com/osmocom/rtl-sdr). Generally, the use of rtl_fm is `rtl_fm -M wbfm -f <frequency in hertz> | aplay -r 32000 -f S16_LE -c 1`  . To seek, you'd need to end the process by sending an interrupt, then run it again at the new frequency. to avoid this, and also allow it to accept socket commands (such as SEEK_UP, etc), I decided to modify rtl_fm, and to play the sounds directly using ALSA.

But I'll be honest, my audio programming skills are limited to this project. I've managed to get it to play audio but it stutters constantly. afaik, it's not caused by an underrun (I don't get an -EPIPE error), and the same code minus my modifications works fine when piped to aplay.

Normally, it outputs audio to STDOUT via:
rtl_fm.c

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&s->rw);
fwrite(s->result, 2, s->result_len, s->file);
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&s->rw);
```

I've modified it to:
rtl_fm_player.c

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&s->rw);
if ((p->pcm_error = snd_pcm_writei(p->pcm_handle, s->result, s->result_len)) == -EPIPE)
{
    snd_pcm_prepare(p->pcm_handle);
}
else if (p->pcm_error < 0)
{
    printf("ERROR. Can't write to PCM device. %s\n", snd_strerror(p->pcm_error));
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&s->rw);
```

the player is setup according to the following (error checking omitted for brevity):
rtl_fm_player.c

```
void player_setup(struct player_state * o)
{
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params; 
    /* Open the PCM device in playback mode */

    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_open(&(o->pcm_handle), PCM_DEVICE, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)

    /* Allocate parameters object and fill it with default values*/

    //alloca puts params on the stack, no need to free it.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(o->pcm_handle, params);

    /* Update relevant parameters to new values */
    //interleaved
    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(o->pcm_handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)

    //16 bit little endian raw data
    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(o->pcm_handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)

    //channels
    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(o->pcm_handle, params, o->channels)

    //sample rate
    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(o->pcm_handle, params, &(o->rate), 0)

    /* Write parameters to pcm_handler */
    o->pcm_error = snd_pcm_hw_params(o->pcm_handle, params)

    //snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(params, &(o->bufferSize));
    fifo_init(o->fifo, o->output_size * 8);
    o->setup = true;
}
```

Player State is a struct storing rate, channels, output_size, etc. rate = 32000, channels = 1. currently output_size is unused.

Full code is here, if that helps https://bitbucket.org/ab6393/rtl_fm-player.

in the event this also helps, the verbose logging of aplay when rtl_fm is piped to it, assuming I missed setting some hw param.

```
Playing raw data 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 32000 Hz, Mono
Plug PCM: Rate conversion PCM (44100, sformat=S16_LE)
Converter: linear-interpolation
Protocol version: 10002
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK  
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED  
  format       : S16_LE  
  subformat    : STD  
  channels     : 1  
  rate         : 32000  
  exact rate   : 32000 (32000/1)  
  msbits       : 16  
  buffer_size  : 5944  
  period_size  : 743
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 743
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 5944
  stop_threshold   : 5944
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 779091968
Slave: Route conversion PCM (sformat=S16_LE)
  Transformation table:
    0 <- 0
    1 <- 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1073741824
Slave: Soft volume PCM
Control: PCM
min_dB: -51
max_dB: 0
resolution: 256
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1073741824
Slave: Direct Stream Mixing PCM
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1073741824
Hardware PCM card 0 'snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 23219
  tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 1073741824
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 1073741824
  boundary     : 1073741824
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
Aborted by signal Interrupt...
```

As far as I can tell the setting are identical to running aplay, but the result differs. If anyone can tell me what I'm screwing up, that'd be much appreciated.